# VBA Conditional Formatting with "AND" equation

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, vba

**UPDATE**

Thank you for the assistance. I have updated my code to look like:

```
Sub AddColor()

With Sheet1.Range("$T$3:$T$3600").FormatConditions

     .Delete
     With .Add(xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(($Q3+7)<=TODAY(),$Q3>0,$T3="""")")
     .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240)
     .StopIfTrue = False
     End With
     With .Add(xlExpression, Formula2:="=AND(($Q3+14)<=TODAY(),$Q3>0,$T3="""")")
     .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
     .StopIfTrue = True
End With
End With

With Sheet1.Range("$U$3:$U$3600").FormatConditions
    .Delete
    With .Add(xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(($S3-1)<=TODAY(),$S3>0,$U3="""")")
    .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240)
    .StopIfTrue = False
    End With
    With .Add(xlExpression, Formula2:="=AND(($T3+1)<=TODAY(),$U3="""",$T3>0)")
    .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .StopIfTrue = True

 End With
End With
'Code continues
```

I am now getting an error that says "Argument Not Optional" and it seems to be referring to my "Formula2" line on the first set of statements. I am not sure what argument is missing, as it is working correctly for the first statement. I tried to skip over the second formula and it has the same error for the next set for arguments.

It is probably something simple, but any assistance is appreciated!

**UPDATE**

I am trying to add conditional formatting through VBA, but am running into some issues with my code. I would like to be able to do it through the conditional formatting function, but the data that is going to be imported requires that i split columns, which causes the reference cells to change, but conditional formatting does not seem to keep it how I want it (long story). Anyway, I have about 10 more of these to format the information in the corresponding columns and am just trying to figure out why I keep getting an error. Here is what I have:

```
Sub AddColor()
With Sheet1.Range("$T$3:$T$3600")

     .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(($Q3+7)
<=TODAY(),$Q3>0,$T3="")"
     .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240)
     .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
     .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula2:="=AND(($Q3+14)
<=TODAY(),$Q3>0,$T3=0)"
     .FormatConditions(2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
     .FormatConditions(2).StopIfTrue = True
End With

With Sheet1.Range("$U$3:$U$3600")
    .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1 = "=AND(($S3-1 
<=TODAY(),$S3>0,$U3="")"
    .FormatConditions(3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240)
    .FormatConditions(3).StopIfTrue = False
    .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula2 = "=AND(($T3+1)
<=TODAY(),$U3="",$T3>0)"
    .FormatConditions(4).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .FormatConditions(4).StopIfTrue = True

End With
```

(the<=TODAY() portion is a continuation i my code, it just jumped to the next line due to formatting.) What am I doing wrong? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I answered my own question. The issue that I had was that after each "End With" it wants the next formula to still be labeled as "Formula1" instead of using "Formula2" within the same range.

Answer (score 2):

Your statement

```
.FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(($Q3+7)<=TODAY(),$Q3>0,$T3="")"
```

is trying to tell Excel to use a formula of `=AND(($Q3+7)<=TODAY(),$Q3>0,$T3=")`.  That is syntactically incorrect, as there is no closing quote for the part that starts `$T3="`.

You need to escape all double-quotation marks (`"`) within string literals in VBA code by using two double-quotation marks (i.e. `""`) for every one you actually want in the string.

I believe you want your code to be:

```
Sub AddColor()
With Sheet1.Range("$T$3:$T$3600")
     .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(($Q3+7)<=TODAY(),$Q3>0,$T3="""")"
     .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240)
     .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
     .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula2:="=AND(($Q3+14)<=TODAY(),$Q3>0,$T3=0)"
     .FormatConditions(2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
     .FormatConditions(2).StopIfTrue = True
End With

With Sheet1.Range("$U$3:$U$3600")
    .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(($S3-1)<=TODAY(),$S3>0,$U3="""")"
    .FormatConditions(3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240)
    .FormatConditions(3).StopIfTrue = False
    .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, Formula2:="=AND(($T3+1)<=TODAY(),$U3="""",$T3>0)"
    .FormatConditions(4).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .FormatConditions(4).StopIfTrue = True
End With
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the corrections made by YowE3K, I suggest you make a few other improvements. The way you are referring to the newly added CFs is hazardous. I suggest:

1- delete any old CF before adding new ones in the macro. Otherwise they will keep accumulating each time you run the macro and accordingly theit indexes will not be what you "think" they are.

2- Refer explicitly to any newly added CF instead of by index. For example, in the column U, you refer to them as `.FormatConditions(3)` and `(4)`, which is incorrect.

```
With Sheet1.Range("$U$3:$U$3600").FormatConditions
  .Delete  ' <--- delete old CF if any
  With .Add(xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(($S3-1)<=TODAY(),$S3>0,$U3="""")")
    .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 240)
    .StopIfTrue = True
   '...
  End With
  With .Add(xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(($T3+1)<=TODAY(),$U3="""",$T3>0)")
    .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    .StopIfTrue = True
   '...
  End With
End with
```

Apply the same method for each CF you want to add, and don't forget to "double-up" your formula's double-quotes that you embed inside a VBA string.

Comment: This is perfect! I saw the delete  caption in a few examples but they did not seem to be needed. Totally makes sense why I need them, though. Also, the double quote part. Can't believe I missed that. Much appreciated to both of you!!!